# Remove Watermark from GoJs

Tags: canvas, watermark, gojs

can you please tell me how can I remove the watermark from GoJs?

Here is the ScreenShot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Wfh.png)

[go.js file](https://gojs.net/latest/release/go.js)

Comment: If you have bought GoJS and have purchased the unlimited domains use rights - then they provide you with the correct instructions on how to remove the watermark when your custom library is generated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can remove the watermark by [buying GoJS.](https://www.nwoods.com/sales/index.html)